# How to encrypt elements in XML and decrypt them using XSLT1?

Tags: xml, encryption, xslt-1.0

I have seen some questions about this but the examples with coding languages and not XSLT-1.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have a concrete idea? xslt principally is turing-complete, i.e. you *can* do everything that can be calculated. However, some tasks may be really hard and inefficient in practice.

Comment: @StefanHegny I was thinking about encrypting a password. But then I am only going to decrypt it to display it on HTML output so why bother with the encryption in the first place!

Comment: @AndresTruckle passwords normally are hashed... however, in principle, if the encrypted password is base64 (note binary data itself is no possible in xml) then you could split it up into its original byte values and do calculations on that. But it might be one of the most clumsy decryptions ever, even in postscript language it would be more elegant...

Comment: @StefanHegny Don't think I will bother. :)